# PHP regular expression to extract quoted text in tag body

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression in PHP. From this code I want to match 'bar'.

```
<data info="foo">
  "bar"|tr
</data>
```

I tried this two regex, without success. It matches 'foo"> "bar'.

```
$regex = '/"(.*?)"\|tr/s';
$regex = '/"[^"]+(.*?)"\|tr/s';
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash in PHP strings:

```
$regex = '/"([^"]*)"\\|tr/s';
```

I added a capturing group to get the contents of the quotes, which you seem to be interested in.

Since you seem to apply the regex to XML, I just want to warn you that XML and regular expressions don't play well together. Regex is only recommendable in conjunction with a DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
\"\w+\"
```

should match any word char in parenthesis

Comment: I would match also "bar foobar"|tr and not a single word. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$regex = '/"([^">]+)"\|tr/s'
```

If you want to match just letters and numbers, you can do:

```
$regex = '/"([\w\d]+)"\|tr/s'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex = '/"(.+?)"(?=\|tr)/'
```

Will match `"bar"` (including the quotes), and you have the `bar` string (without quotes) in $1.
Uses [look-ahead](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html#10).